# A question about events of specific form

Tags: probability, combinatorics, independence

> Suppose, we flip a fair coin $k$-times. Now suppose $A_1, A_2, ... , A_{2^k}$ are $2^k$ distinct events, such that each of them has non-zero probability. Do there always exist such $2^k$ distinct events $B_1, B_2, ... B_{2^k}$, that satisfy the conditions:
>
> 1)$\forall i \leq 2^k \exists c_i \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $P(B_i) = \frac{1}{2^{c_i}}$
>
> 2)$\forall i, j \leq 2^k$ we have that $B_i$ and $B_j$ are independent iff $A_i$ and $A_j$ are independent.

I manually checked, that this is true for $k \leq 3$, but I do not know, whether this is true in general, or not.

Comment: I have no idea what this means. Why mention the coin flips? Are they related to the $A_i$? You are apparently asking for a set of events $B_j$ each with prob a power of $1/2$ st whether $B_i,B_j$ are independent is specified in advance. Is that right? Maybe you could give an example to clarify what you mean.

Comment: @almagest, for example, the coin is flipped two times. Let’s write the outcomes in the form $(a, b)$, where $a, b \in \{0, 1\}$. Suppose $A_1=\{(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0)\}$, $A_2=\{(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)\}$, $A_3=\{(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0)\}$ and $A_4=\{(1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 0)\}$. Now if we take $B_1 = \{(0,0)\}$, $B_2=\{(0, 1)\}$, $B_3 = \{(1, 0)\}$, $B_4 = \{(1, 1)\}$, they will satisfy our conditions.